# Retrieve parameter from the restlet

Tags: java, restlet

I need to parse the parameter from the following URL:
http://mysite.com/customer/token/name/customerName

So there are two parameters in above case, customer => token and name => customerName.
How do I retrieve parameters (name from the key) for the above url?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
 router.attach("/name/{name}", HelloWorldResource.class);
```

Then access it like:

```
 String m = (String)this.getRequestAttributes().get("name");
```

This is called template.

Comment: If url is: http://[ip]:[port]/api/name/Your Name. With the spaces in url. You will cannot found URI attached. Get request with the params always have pattern is: http://[ip]:port/<static segment>?<dynamic segment>. For example: http://google.com?search="What%20the%20Hell&lang=EN"